# iTunes Connect Role greyed out

Tags: app-store-connect

[image]
I am trying to upgrade few users' role to App Manager but the higher roles are greyed out although I have Admin role in iTunes Connect. Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What happens, if you first un-check developer? Do you have the option for the App Manager then? (Had some similar issues, worked for me that way)

Comment: Admin, Finance, App Manager, Sales and Reports are always greyed out :(